# Alternative super saiyan transformation of Kale, what's it supposed to be? (warning: content of recent episode 101)

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 101, we've seen another transformation of Kale. Instead of having her eyes blank and her muscles inflated, the called "berserker mode", in the alternative transformation she has the regular form of a super saiyan but apparently she keeps a little of her greenish hair/aura (a little more yellowish maybe), and she's weaker than in berserker mode.

Kale in super saiyan Berserker mode:

[image]

Kale alternative super saiyan transformation:

[image]

Kale and Caulifla super saiyan transformations together for comparision:

[image]

What is this transformation supposed to be? Is it a regular super saiyan, or is it a different super saiyan transformation with a different level of power?

Comment: I would say its just the standard ssj transformation(though in this shoot her hair looks a bit different, so it could be powered down "beserker" transformation)

Answer (score -1):

This transformation is the same as Broly, and it's called *The Legendary Saiyan* transformation. It is very rare for a Saiyan to have this ability as we only know two (currently) Saiyan that achieve this Broly and Kale. PS the second image shows the normal SSJ1 as Broly

Comment: The second image is not normal SSJ1, as the hair colour is not yellow, its green

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki you are from Japan? What do they say in Japan about this?

Comment: It's more something in between green and yellow. If you compare the image of Kale in berserker mode with the other one, the first looks almost like pure green when the second has a yellowish tone to it. BTW, the aura in the pictures I posted looks the same color than Caulifla's